# remove terminated users from DISTRIBUTION groups in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, activedirectorymembership

I am working on a solution that will help keep our Active Directory clean, so I want to use a Powershell script that will remove the disabled accounts from all groups.
I got the following script:

```
foreach ($username in (Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Terminated Users,DC=corp,DC=company,DC=com" -filter *)) {

    # Get all group memberships
    $groups = get-adprincipalgroupmembership $username;
    
    # Loop through each group
    foreach ($group in $groups) {
    
        # Exclude Domain Users group
        if ($group.name -ne "domain users") {
    
            # Remove user from group
            remove-adgroupmember -Identity $group.name -Member $username.SamAccountName -Confirm:$false;
    
            # Write progress to screen
            write-host "removed" $username "from" $group.name;
    
            # Define and save group names into filename in c:\temp
            $grouplogfile = "c:\temp\" + $username.SamAccountName + ".txt";
            $group.name >> $grouplogfile
        }
    
    }
}
```

It's working fine but only for security groups. Users are not deleted from distribution groups. I searched the Internet and people mostly suggest to use "Remove DistributionGroup Member" cmdlet. However, this is the Exchange cmdlet and we use Google Workspace for our email, so this cmdlet is not recognized when I run it on the DC.

Any idea how to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The cmdlet `Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` will help:

```
#get all disabled users in specified OU
$disabledUsers = get-aduser -SearchBase "OU=test_piotr,DC=corp,DC=company,DC=com" -LDAPFilter '(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)' -Properties memberof,samaccountname

#Loop through array and remove groupmembership and store operation result in $result
$result = @(
    foreach ($user in $disabledusers){ 
        try {
            #Only process user account if memberships are present
            If ($user.memberof){
                #Remove all memberships the user has currently, no need to exclude domain users as $user.memberof does not return it
                $null = Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user.samaccountname -MemberOf $user.memberof -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction:stop
                write-host "Removed user: $($user.samaccountname) from groups: $($user.memberof -join ',')"
                #Build object for logfile, you could also loop through $user.memberof to create one object per removed group
                $attrsHt = @{
                    smaccountname=$user.samaccountname
                    group=($user.memberof -join ',')
                    status='removed'
                    exception=$null
                }
                New-Object -typename psobject -Property $attrht
            }
        }
        Catch {
            write-error "Failed to remove user: $($user.samaccountname) from groups: $($user.memberof -join ',') - Exception: $_"
            $attrsHt = @{
                smaccountname=$user.samaccountname
                group=($user.memberof -join ',')
                status='error'
                exception=$_
            }
            New-Object -typename psobject -Property $attrht
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: thanks! @Toni can you please check my answer to your post?

Comment: I found a different issue: -Members is not a correct parameter for Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership cmdlet. I changed it to MemberOf and it worked!
Thanks for your help!